# How to avoid page breaks (print / PDF) on text within large HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf, page-break

I have the following single HTML file (style / scripts included): [FQ.html](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByFhlRDkSVPoOVdXalVjRGJObTA)

I have the following issue:
[image: lame page breaks]

I have iterated on solution attempts, the latest attempt for which has some of the following CSS...

```
@media print{
  @page {
    size:1080px 1080px;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  .page-break-before  { page-break-before: always; display:block; width:200%;}
  .page-break  { display:block; page-break-after: always; width:200%; }
}
```

...and Javascript.

```
//set viewport height in print mode.
var height = 780;  //screen.height;
//pick up the total table.
var table = $('#identification_section > table')[0];
//initialize the sum variable with height of title (h2 tag)
var sum = 24;
//loop all table rows including child tables 
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
  //tr is the parent table row which may contain child table.
  var tr = row;
  if (tr.offsetHeight > height) {  //if row's hight is bigger than viewport height, it contains child table.
    var child_table = tr.cells[0].children[0]; 
    if (child_table.className=="group-table") {  //pick up child table.
      var child_sum = 0;
      for (var j=0, subrow; subrow = child_table.rows[j]; j++) {
        var subtr = subrow;  //pick up child table's row
        child_sum += subtr.offsetHeight; // sum up the row's height.
        if (child_table.rows[j+1]!=null) //check if next row is existing, not end row.
          if (child_sum + child_table.rows[j+1].offsetHeight > height) {  // if (sum of table rows so far + next row's height) > viewport height
            //var temp = subtr.cells[0]; // pick up the first cell of row
            child_table.rows[j+1].classList.add('page-break-before'); // set the page-break-before to next row.
            subtr.classList.add('page-break'); // set the page-break to current row
            child_sum = 0; // set the sum 0 for next page calculation.
          }
      }
    }
  }

  sum += tr.offsetHeight; // sum up the height of parent rows.
  //tr.cells[0].setAttribute('style', 'height:'+tr.offsetHeight+'px');
  if (table.rows[i+1]!=null) // check if there is next row.
    if (sum + table.rows[i+1].offsetHeight>height) {  // if sum + next row'height is bigger than viewport row
      //var temp = tr.cells[0];
      table.rows[i+1].classList.add('page-break-before'); //set the page-break-before class to next row
      tr.classList.add('page-break'); // set the page-break class to current row
      sum = 0; //set the sum 0 for next page calculation.
    }
}
```

However, I am still at a loss. Rather than trying to avoid breaking on text, I felt it would be easier to avoid breaking on a . Even trying that, though, there are 2 or more issues with my attempted solution. One is that the breaks are overly excessive, and the second is that somehow some of the 's no longer seem to have width set at 50%.

Would be great to prevent breaks on text or 's, preferably text.

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply `page-break-before` and `page-break-after` rules to all of the elements inside the document.

For instance, for the tables, you may use `table tr` and similar selectors.